# Advice for Simplifying code to Load an XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, refactoring

I finally finished my XML parsing code, and now looking at it, it scares me.  This code is for a simple Android-based, text adventure game.

I have all my data about encounters, locations, and characters stored in XML files in the 'res' folder.

I coded this XML parser to go through the XML files and store data into a class called Encounter. I can then access the data inside Encounter anywhere in my code.

So I guess I got the OOP part down.  But the actual parsing just looks so messy.

Is there a better way to go about parsing XML data?

Here is my code:

```
public class XmlParser extends Activity  {

private String xmlValue;
private int encounterID;
Encounter encounter;

public XmlParser()
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
     String elName = xpp.getName();
     if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {     //creature
         eventType = xpp.next();

         //top level nodes
         if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("identity")){
             eventType = xpp.next();
             if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                 encounter.name = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("race")) {
                 encounter.race = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("gender")) {
                 encounter.gender = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("alignment")) {
                 encounter.alignment = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.age = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }
             }
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("appearance")) {
             eventType = xpp.next();
             if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")){
                 encounter.condition = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("skinColor")) {
                 encounter.skinColor = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("hairColor")) {
                 encounter.hairColor = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("size")) {
                 encounter.size = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("height")) {
                 encounter.height = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("weight")) {
                 encounter.weight = xpp.getText();
             }

         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("stats")) {
             eventType = xpp.next();
             if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("hitPoints")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.HP = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("armorClass")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.AC = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }                   
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("actionPoints")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.AP = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }                   
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("magicPoint")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.AP = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }                   
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("strength")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.strength = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }                   
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("dexterity")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.dexterity = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("intelligence")) {
                 try {
                     encounter.intelligence = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText());
                 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                     //ok
                 }
             }

         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("inventory")) {
             eventType = xpp.next();
             if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("weapon")) {
                 encounter.weapon = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("armor")) {
                 encounter.armor = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("magicItem")) {
                 encounter.magicItem = xpp.getText();
             }

         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("magic")) {
            eventType = xpp.next();
            if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("attackSpell")) {
                encounter.attackSpell = xpp.getText();
            } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("defenseSpell")) {
                encounter.defenseSpell = xpp.getText();
            }
         } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("treasureItems")) {
             eventType = xpp.next();
             if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("item1")) {
                 encounter.item1 = xpp.getText();
             } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("item2")) {
                 encounter.item2 = xpp.getText();
             }
         }
     } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
         //System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
     }
     eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    //System.out.println("End document");
}
```

In case anyone is interested, here is my XML file for encounters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<encounters>
<creature id="1" type="monster">
    <identity>
        <name></name>
        <race></race>
        <gender></gender>
        <age></age>
        <alignment></alignment>
    </identity>

    <appearance>
        <condition></condition>
        <skinColor></skinColor>
        <hairColor></hairColor>
        <size></size>
        <height></height>
        <weight></weight>
    </appearance>

    <stats>
        <hitPoints></hitPoints>
        <armorClass></armorClass>
        <actionPoints></actionPoints>
        <magicPoints></magicPoints>
        <strength></strength>
        <dexterity></dexterity>
        <intelligence></intelligence>
    </stats>

    <inventory>
        <weapon></weapon>
        <armor></armor>
        <magicItem></magicItem>
    </inventory>

    <magic>
        <attackSpell></attackSpell>
        <defenseSpell></defenseSpell>
    </magic>

    <treasureItems>
        <item1></item1>
        <item2></item2>
    </treasureItems>

</creature>
```

Comment: Not a suggestion to make the code less complicated, but you are using tons of try/catch blocks without using the exception that gets thrown by them. Now if anything goes wrong in that part of your code, you won't even know it went wrong. Might be a good idea to actually use those exceptions, even if it's just to print a stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/), the lightweight library works 
excellent with android (the larger does too, but it is much larger in filesize).
There is also the [SAX-parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) that comes with android.

Other than that, when I use the XmlPullParser, I usually have a map with the tagnames as keys and integers, then I can just get the value from the map and then use a simple switch, which clears up the code a bit:

```
//Before parsing, or if used frequently the map can be put outside the method and reused:
final HashMap<String, Integer> tags = new HashMap<String, Integer>(9, 1);
tags.put("encounters", 0);
tags.put("identity", 1);
tags.put("name", 2);
//And so on...

//in your parse-loop:
int tag = tags.get(xpp.getName());
switch(tag){
case 0: //Handle encounter tag...
break;
case 1: //Handle identity tag...
break;
case 2: //Handle name tag...
break;
//For all tags.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I thought SAX was mainly for XML documents that were accessed via a URL.  My XML docs are on the phone in the 'res' folder.

Comment: You are welcome, I have never had any use for sax really as I've always found that the VTDXML or XmlPullParser has been better for my needs.

Comment: Hi Jave - What do you mean when you say " map with the tagnames as keys"? ---thanks

Comment: Thanks...I think I get it.  So you would check the name of the element first?  Would you loop through the XML file?  ---thanks

Comment: Yes, the switch would just be to get rid of all the 'else if' and equalsIgnoreCase(), so essentially it would be exactly the same, but with less code and comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with XML that has a direct object mapping, as in your case, I usually tend to use a marshalling technology. The most standard nowadays is JAXB. However it add quite a bit overhead (aprox 9 megs) to your application, which is not negligible in a mobile application. In this case a more lightweight marshalling API such as [simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), can have a niche.